# How does CDataStream data find its way into a socket?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I am curious to know how and where in the source code, the data from stream is actually sent by a node. As per my understanding the following occurs:

- `ProcessMessage()` issues a `PushMessage()` with appropriate parameters
- `PushMessage()` will basically send message headers and parameters into a stream `ssData`
- `ssData` is object of `CDataStream` and defined in `CNode`
- `CDataStream` is in `src/stream.h` has no information related to IP or Port

How does the data being pushed to a stream goes into the correct socket in bitcoin working. Only `CNode` class has information on the network address (IP) and TCP Port. How is this information picked up by the datastream?

**Adding more findings:**

I found this from https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41727.0

```
The socket thread reads the sockets and places data into a CDataStream
associated with each node called vRecv. The Satoshi client uses C++
serialization operators >> and << to read and write to a CDataStream
and then it uses generic routines to move the data between the streams
and sockets
```

My exact question is where(what) are these mentioned generic routines in source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CNode` has a method `SocketSendData()` which pushes all the serialized data into the socket.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SocketSendData&type=Code